# STEEL CONNECTIONS

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, steel

[image]

Hi, so, would you consider  the connection detailed here as fixed or pinned during your structural analysis?

Comment: Have a read of this, and then come back and either answer your own question, or comment your best guess if you're still not sure - this is a well-trodden topic, and you should be able to work it out with a bit of research: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-differentiate-between-a-Pin-Joint-and-a-Rigid-Joint

Comment: Just go with pinned if you really have to. It might be a little bit less economical but still correct results.

Comment: I would say that the connection is supposed to be fixed.  The fact that the flanges are able to transmit the force to the columns would clearly suggest that. But where I work it's always taken as pinned. So I was wondering why be so conservative?